# Publish option missing Visual Studio 2015 Professional

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, publish, webdeploy

I have a web api project and does not matter how I selected the publish menu (right click on the web api project or Build -> publish), it never appears the options.

[image]

Publish button message:

> Please select a profile to publish.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @jazzcat not exactly, I'm using SVN (TFS to be more specific), then I had to publish the project using other machine where the project/visual studio were working fine and include (check in) the "code/settings/config" to the SVN. when I got the "code/settings/config" everything starts to work fine again.

Answer (score 1):

For me the fix was to upgrade to Visual Studio 2017. It works fine with VS2015 project files and solutions, does not try to "convert" them or anything.